# How customize ChatBot apparence

Tags: chatbot

I would like to customize my chatbot, but I don't know what technology I need to do that. Can I use css?

Tanks

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO!. Do take a look at our [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it helps us help you. Looking at your question, the only answer I can give is "yes", but without knowing the technologies you are using for your chatbot or knowing what you have tried, others may find difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the botframework, [they released some time ago the source code of the WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). Clone the repo and start building your own WebChat with the instructions they provide, and yes, you can customize the appearance of your chatbot using css

Once you make the changes you want in the logic or the appearance, build the webchat and you'll get 3 files that you need to paste in your chatbot project:

- `/botchat.js` - contains the logic of the webchat
- `/botchat.css` - contains the appearance
- `/botchat-fullwindow.css` - appearance for full-window experience